# Allow ClickOnce application to read/write to c:\ProgramData

Tags: c#-4.0, clickonce

I store my Database in the c:\ProgramData\MyApp folder. How can I get access to that folder? I see there's a way to edit the App manifest to allow permissions, but I can't seem to find the proper permission.

The app is installed from the internet.

Anyone know the trick here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Normal users do not have write access to this folder.
You need to run as Administrator.

If you want to, you can run as Administrator once, create your subfolder, and modify its permissions to grant access to the Users group.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, it's not possible to run a ClickOnce app as administrator.... at least not manually (there's no option when right clicking)

Comment: @Chu: I don't know much about ClickOnce.  However, you can run a separate process as administrator from inside your app.